# what is the difference between uri and tagdir in JSP taglib

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, taglib, web-development-server

I am cofused between `tagdir` and `uri` used in `taglib` directive.
What is the real difference between using `tagdir` and `uri`?

Examples :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="notMyTags" %>

<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="otherTags" %>

<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="myTags" %>
```

to the best of my understanding:

1) I can access non-custom tags from the `uri` referencing them by the provided `prefix` (e.g.: if the `uri` defines the tag `hello`, in the page where `taglib-uri` is pasted, I can access it as `<notMyTags:hello>` or `<otherTags:hello>`).

2) I can access custom tags defined within the path specified in `tagdir` referencing them by their `.tag` filenames because each custom tag corresponds to a `.tag` file (e.g.: if `hello.tag` is a file in the `tagDir` specified path, in the page where `taglib` is pasted, I can access it as `<myTags:hello>`)

Comment: You supply the tagdir attribute to identify the location of the files. The uri attribute refers to a URI that uniquely identifies the tag library descriptor (TLD)

Answer (score 0):

The two directive are used for two different concepts of custom JSP tags.

1) You use `uri` to reference a tag *library*, which is usually delivered in a jar and/or defined in a `.tld` file. These can be written in Java (implementing one of the `javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.JspTag' subinterfaces) or as plain JSP tagfiles.

2) You use `tagdir` to reference JSP tagfiles within `/WEB-INF/tags` (or subdirectories thereof). Those can not be Java classes.

See the J2EE tutorial at Orcale's website for more information regarding JSP tagfiles:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html