# Tag file directory /WEB-INF/functions.tld does not start with "/WEB-INF/tags"

Tags: java, jsp-tags

I have an interesting issue...  I am trying to add a JSP Tag to my application.  I have stored a `functions.tld` in `/WEB-INF/tags/` but I get the error message `Illegal TLD path /WEB-INF/tags/functions.tld, must not start with "/WEB-INF/tags"` so I tried to move it `/WEB-INF/` which I then get `Tag file directory /WEB-INF/functions.tld does not start with "/WEB-INF/tags"`. So where am I supposed to put it!!

TLD File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
        version="2.1">

    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>my</short-name>

    <!-- Invoke 'Generate' action to add tags or functions -->
    <function>
        <name>urlencode</name>
        <function-class>library.StringUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String urlencode(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>

</taglib>
```

JSP File

```
<%@ taglib prefix="f" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/functions.tld" %>
```

Error when not in tag folder

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6191: Tag file directory /WEB-INF/functions.tld does not start with "/WEB-INF/tags"
```

Error when in /tag/ folder

```
  Error invoking ServletContainerInitializer org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6336: Illegal TLD path /WEB-INF/tags/functions.tld, must not start with "/WEB-INF/tags"
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.processTldsInFileSystem(TldScanner.java:573)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.processTldsInFileSystem(TldScanner.java:566)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanTlds(TldScanner.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.onStartup(TldScanner.java:242)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:5713)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5609)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:900)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:684)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1690)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
  Startup of context  failed due to previous errors]]
```

Comment: What happens when you use the uri attribute, `<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="/WEB-INF/functions.tld" %>` ?

Comment: Perhaps it helps that I explain why I ask that question: I found it strange that you would use an attribute named *tagdir* to refer to a tag *file* and thus looked up how to define a custom taglib, which led to an example using the uri attribute.

Comment: @Gimby It doesn't error :) . Checking it works.....

Comment: @Gimby yep, it works.  Would you like to put it in an Answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple misunderstanding. Reasoning about it a little, it does not make much sense to use an attribute *tagdir* to refer to a single tag *file*. The correct way to achieve it is to indeed put the TLD file in the WEB-INF directory and then refer to it using

```
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="/WEB-INF/functions.tld" %>
```

In other words: replace **tagdir** with **uri**.

This [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893729/what-is-the-difference-between-uri-and-tagdir-in-jsp-taglib) and answer explains the difference.